# Keep Entity Framework From Executing Properties or Extension Methods

Tags: linq, entity-framework-5

I am using EF5 Code First models. Consider the following Entity Framework query:

```
var results = from i in context.Table1
            where i.ID == Id // passed in
            select new TableInfo()
            {
                Name = i.Name,
                ActionDate = i.Action.ActionDate,
                CreatedDate = i.Action.CreatedDate,
                CreatedBy = i.Action.CreatedBy.FullName
            };
```

The FullName property is defined thusly:

```
[NotMapped]
[Display(Name = "Full Name")]
public string FullName
{
    get
    {
        string ret = string.Empty;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(LAST_NAME) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(FIRST_NAME))
        {
            return "";
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Format("{0}, {1}", LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME);
        }

    }
}
```

I get the error:

> The specified type member 'FullName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

I get a similar error if I create an extension method to do the same thing. So the question is how do I keep EF from trying to run these things on the data store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the expression in the initializer of the select clause:

```
CreatedBy = i.Action.CreatedBy.FullName
```

This is causing the Linq-to-Entity provider to try to find a mapping for the property named "FullName". The same applies to if you try to use an extension method.

You can do this though:

```
var results = 
    from i in context.Table1
    where i.ID == Id // passed in
    select new TableInfo()
    {
        Name = i.Name,
        ActionDate = i.Action.ActionDate,
        CreatedDate = i.Action.CreatedDate,
        CreatedBy = i.Action.CreatedBy
    };
```

And then use `item.CreatedBy.FullName` to access the name via your custom property